# not able to disable a particular text block in custom control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a custom control which contains one text-block, one combo-box and one hyper-link button.

```
<UserControl x:Class="IXExpress.Controls.WorkspaceIndexes"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:telerikSdk="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">                        
            <TextBlock x:Name="IndexNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding ApplicationStrings.SelectIndexName, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="3,5" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <telerikSdk:RadComboBox x:Name="IndexNameCB"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="IndexName"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        IsDropDownOpen="False"
                                        Margin="3,0,3,5"
                                        MinWidth="150"
                                        Width="150"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Visibility="Visible"
                                        SelectionChanged="IndexNameCB_SelectionChanged"/>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="CreateNewIndexLink"
                                 Content="Create New"                                
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Click="CreateNewIndexLink_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am using it on another page as following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <customControls:WorkspaceIndexes x:Name="WorkspaceIndexes" IsMoreTextRequired="True" Margin="3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The issue is, on some condition when I want to disable this control but it only disables combo-box and hyper-link button.

code:

```
if (my condition)
    WorkspaceIndexes.IsEnabled = true;
  else
    WorkspaceIndexes.IsEnabled = false;
```

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u5Og.jpg

I also don't see IsEnabled option for "IndexNameTextBlock" text-block, Why is that?

Comment: Found a solution!!! Here for some reason I am unable to use IsEnabled property in text block so I am changing the font color it self.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the `IsEnabled` property for the `TextBlock` because it doesn't have the property. The other Elements are derived from `Control`, they can be enabled and disabled. **The TextBlock is no Control.** Disabling a TextBlock would be meaningless. It just displays text. No user interaction possible.

If you need it to be grayed out you have to change either its `Foreground` color, or reduce its `Opacity`, or place a semi-transparent Rectangle/Border over it.